# Changing fragments dynamically - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning how to program in Android and I'm having some problems about changing my fragments. I tried almost all the solutions that I found here but they aren't working.

Here is my layout that I'm trying to show in screen:

**fragment_result.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.ic.projeto_final.ResultFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/resultView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".90"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".10"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="setaesq - pegar cod ascii"
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
                />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".80"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/fileName" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:id="@+id/fileDistance" >
                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/fileImage"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="seta dir pegar cod ascii"
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fazer nova consulta"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/btnNovaConsulta"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And the class related:

**ResultFragment.java**

```
public class ResultFragment extends Fragment {   

public ResultFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container, false);      

    TextView fileName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
    TextView fileDistance = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileDistance);

    ImageView imageName = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fileImage);

    Button btnPrevious = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    Button btnNext = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

And this is the part in my mainActivity that tries to change the fragment displayed:

**MainActivityFragment.java**

```
btnConsulta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


       /* Others pieces of code that not affect this part */  

                ResultFragment result = new ResultFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.resultView, result);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

Currently, the error shown in my logcat is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a000f (com.example.ic.projeto_final:id/resultView) for fragment ResultFragment{143a9831 #0 id=0x7f0a000f}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:886)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And I also tried to use getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager(), associating the id to the FrameLayout in fragment_result.xml, but it doesn't work too.

If there is anything missing that I need to show in order to solve the problem, just let me know

Comment: Seems like `resultView` is within your fragment, *not* your activity.

Comment: I'm starting to understand how to handle this after you pointed this, thank you. I'm doing some tests and it's almost working. My last problem now is that the old xml is still appearing in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main activity xml file put in it this:

```
< FrameLayout
android:id = "@+id/resultView"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android_layout_hight = "match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: I tried your idea right now, but the problem still persists

Comment: what is the type of your resultView? is ia a FrameLayout? did you created your resultView ? It should be created in the xml of your main activity. I updated my code

Comment: It was outside the main activity xml. I read David's commentary and I started to understand this. I did the same thing as you and almost worked, but the old xml is still visible in the background.

Comment: You have to use a background color in te layout of the new fragment so it show above the old layout because the default color is transparent like this: android:background = "#FFFFFF". then you ned to activate the following method: android:clickable = "true" so the click only responds to the added layout and not to the layout that is in background